# Pod install using Custom action script for SourceTree

Tags: git, macos, scripting, cocoapods, atlassian-sourcetree

I wrote a custom post-checkout git hook to check for a pod file and perform pod install. I added this as a custom action in SourceTree. Whenever I try to trigger from Sourcetree this it throws an error "pod not found". But, If I run this script independently it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the script target to `pod` and `install` as a parameter.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks to Michael Voong [Blog](http://www.michaelvoong.com/2015/04/12/pod-installupdate-via-sourcetree-shortcut/)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a file named pod_install.sh with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

And I also added this custom action:
[image: Custom Action]

If you need permission to execute, just go to command line in terminal where the script is and run:

```
chmod a+x pod_install.sh
```